# Host file is open in another process

Tags: hosts-file

I am trying to edit my host file under

```
C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc
```

But I keep getting the message

```
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
```

My PC has been restarted a few times, even tried full shut down and searched through possible programs that might be using it.

I found a way to edit the file with the command prompt, but still gave the same message?

Hope someone can help!

Comment: Are you opening this file with the editor (that is notepad) opened with admin privileges?

Comment: yes, tried with notepad and Aptana Studios 3, both right clicked and opened with Admin priveges. I also tried copying the content of the hosts file and save/replace the original one, got the same message, but when I save with a different name, it saves

Comment: You may be able to edit in safe mode; otherwise, you'll need to boot up an alternative operating system from an external disc.

Comment: You can try to find out what is locking hosts by starting process explorer (from msdn) with admin privilege and searching for the file name (that is "hosts") .https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx

Comment: I was able to edit and save in safemode, so Thanx AFH, you can post as a answer

Comment: @RickusHarmse Some security/anti-virus programs lock the file so that it cannot be modified by malware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in a comment in the question by AFH -

> You may be able to edit in safe mode

I was able to log into windows 10 safe mode by following
[these steps](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/start-your-pc-in-safe-mode).

I could edit and save the file without the popup stopping me

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do this is, Copy hosts file to desktop edit it and then copy it back to the original location and replace the original file.

Comment: I could not do this, because it always said the file is in use, so I cannot replace the file

Answer (score 0):

Turning off webroot secure fixed the problem for me.  If you're not using webroot secure try turning off any antivirus/malware/spyware apps you are running temporarily.

An easy way to see what process is using it, try moving the host file to the desktop and it will tell you.

Comment: Awesome this worked for me. Just turned off real time shield in webroot then I was able to save.